# Order functions by growth

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to order some functions by their growth rate. All logarithms have 2 as their base. These are the functions:

```
2n+(n log n)
3logn
(n∑i=1i)2
4^n/n^4
n^(7/8)
2n
10logn
n (log n)!
√log5n
n^(log n)
```

I tried plotting them but I'm still very confused as to what the correct order is. Any idea as to how I have to order them? I also tried calculating their big-o limits but some won't return 0 or infinity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering functions by Asymptotic Growth Rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003269/ordering-functions-by-asymptotic-growth-rate)

Comment: What do **you** think the order is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 2*n+(n log n)==> o(n log n)
2. 3*log n ==> o(log n)
3. 1+2+3+...=[n(n+1)]/2 ==> o(n^2)
4. (4^n)/(n^4) ==> o((4^n)/(n^4))
5. n^(7/8) ==> o(n^(7/8))
6. 2*n  ==> o(n)
7. 10*log n==> o(log n)
8. n*(log n)!==> o(n*(log n)!)
9. sqrt(log 5*n) ==> o(sqrt(n))
10. n^(log n) ==> o(n^(log n))

Hence:

```
2=7<9<5<6<3<8<10<4
```